# Adding onChange script to input box in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I currently have an input box component and I'd like to add a script to prevent all input except for numbers.

```
function onChangeHandler(e: React.ChangeEvent) {
  this.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,'');
}

export function Input(props: InputProps) {
  const {
    className,
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  return (
    <input
      {...restProps}
      className={cx([inputStyles])}
      type={inputType}
      onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e)}
    />
  );
}
```

Currently this setup doesn't work because I get the following error from `onChangeHandler`: `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

How can I make this work?

Note: I don't want to use `type=number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access this scope when there does not exist any. It's not a class, it's a function, `this` is not required here.

Your code should look like this (though, you could move `value` state to your parent component and pass it through props):

```
export function Input(props: InputProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');  

  const {
    className,
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  const onChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    setValue(e.target.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,''));
  }

  return (
    <input
      {...restProps}
      className={cx([inputStyles])}
      type={inputType}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
  );
}
```